# Page becomes white when tapped in IOS7 + Phonegap

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, safari, ios7

In my Phonegap application using jQuery, jQuerymobile, after the page is loaded in IOS7, tapping on any part of the page is making the page white and all the content is gonehis is happening only on Ipad4 retina display. I am using all the re-render techniques and translatez(0) onload of this page and tried to fix it but nothing works.. any help?

This is my screen. The images are image tag with image data. The height and width of each div inside is calculated dynamically. Each div with image is having `position:relative` and for scrolling I am using `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch`

```
width = window.innerWidth-20;
colWidth = Math.floor(width/3);
imgWidth = colWidth-75;                     
$("#div_all_subcategories_level2").css("width",width+"px");
$(".sw1").css("width",(colWidth-25)+"px").css("height",(colWidth-25)+"px");
$(".cls_img_subcat_l2").css("width",colWidth-25+"px").css("height",colWidth-25+"px");
```

[image]

Comment: can u post your code?

Comment: I have edited my post with some more information